# How do we write a locally free resolution for...

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let's $C \subset X$ be a smooth curve inside a three dimensional variety with split normal bundle $N_C^X= \nu_1 \oplus \nu_2$. What is a locally free resolution of $\iota_{*}\mathcal{O}_{C}$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, there is no straight way to write such a resolution (note by the way, that a resolution is in no way unique!). However, in some cases there is a distinguished resolution. For example, if $C$ is the zero locus of a global section of a rank 2 vector bundle $E$ then there is a Koszul resolution
$$
0 \to \det E^* \to E^* \to O_X \to \iota_*O_C \to 0.
$$
Another case, is when $C$ is the degeneration locus of a morphism $\phi:E \to F$ of vector bundles such that $rank(E) = rank(F) - 1$. Then there is a resolution 
$$
0 \to E\otimes L \to F\otimes L \to O_X \to \iota_*O_C \to 0,
$$
where $L =\det E\otimes (\det F)^{-1}$.

Comment: But for example if X is Quintic and C a balanced rational curve with normal bundle $O(-1)\oplus O(-1)$ then C does not come from a section of a rank two bundle? does it ?  Then what should I do for this specific example?

Comment: It comes --- there is a construction (known as the Serre construction) of a rank 2 vector bundle from a locally complete intersection subscheme of codimension 2 the determinant of the normal bundle of which extends to the ambient variety. The bondle is constructed together with a regular section the zero locus of which is the initial subscheme.

Comment: can you give a reference for this type of constructions?
Thanks

Comment: See for example Okonek, Schneider, Spindler "Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces", section 5.1.

Comment: For general smooth variety $X \subset \mathbb{C}P^n$ of codimesnion $r$, Is there any criteria under which we know there is a vector bundle $E$ of rank $r$, admitting a section $s$ such that $s^{-1}(0)=X$.

Is there a general way of constructing such a bundle for each $X$.

Comment: I guess for $r > 2$ nothing is known.